# How to open a file with ".$$1" format

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have ordered a data from an organization. They provided me with a huge file with `.$$1` extension.

I just what to know what is this file and how can I open it with R or python?

I first tried to open this file with notepad++, but it was not a text file.
7-zip shows that it contains worksheets with a `json` in it, but it failed to extract it.

Notepad++ sliced output of the first line:

```
PK    .vëT.¶ç#¢I]îº™ªx   xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
```

Comment: Can you share a small sample of the file, first n lines?

Comment: File format is not necessarily defined by extension.  Surely your supplier provided a file specification?(Or your organisation defined one in the contract?)

Comment: @Clemsang I tried. It is a binary. It could not read it.

Comment: @Limey They sent me their database.

Comment: @JohnnyJohnBoy I tried to open it with text editor but it is a binary.

Comment: Have you tried opening it in Excel?  Might be an XLS binary?

Comment: Did you try copy file then change file extension to xls or xlsx and open it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it starts with `b'PK'`, try unzip the file

```py
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(file, "r", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zfile:
    zfile.extractall()
```

or open it with excel